# Record property with getter - left side cannot be assigned to

Tags: delphi

I have this declaration :

```
type
   TForm1 = class(TForm)
   private
     FRect: TrectF;
   public
     property Rect: TrectF read FRect;
   end;
```

now If I try to do something like this :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Rect.left := 25;
end;
```

it's fail at compile time with "left side cannot be assigned to" that is quite good.
now if I do strictly the same thing but in a different way :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Rect.width := 25;
end;
```

then it's work :( Is there any explanation for that behavior?

Comment: .Left is a field whilst .Width is a property, which I think has something to do with it.  But it's still odd.

Comment: `TRectF` contains a property called `width` that has both read and write.

Comment: yes I agree that Widh is a property of TrectF, but in background this property just change it's left member so it's must be strictly the same behavior :(

Comment: Left is not a property. I do not think you can override every property of a record when you make the record itself a property with read only. You'll still be able to access the properties of the record normally. You can attempt to make overrides for the properties as shown here. Just scroll a bit down to Property Overrides: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Properties_(Delphi)

Comment: The "already answered" question is about whey you can't assign to a field of the record.  One or two of the answers mention that you can assign to a property of a record, but it doesn't explain why, at least not directly that I can see.

Comment: @Adriaan property overrides apply to descendant _classes_ so are not applicable for records.

Comment: Updating/correcting my earlier comment, the _first_ "already answered" question doesn't explain why assigning to properties works, but the _second_ one does.